# JupyterLab Studio - Use Python 3.10 + CUDA + Pytorch kernel

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In JupyterLab Studio I'd like to use a Python 3.10 + CUDA + Pytorch kernel.
The documentation says that such kernel exists and how to change it.
But in practice there only exist 2 kernels, Python 3.8 and 3.9, without CUDA and PyTorch.

I tried to change kernel or add a new kernel. But there is no such kernel as stated in the docs. And no option to add a new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Studio JupyterLab apps use the [SageMaker distribution](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-distribution) base image. So, you'll have a single Python kernel that has most commonly used packages pre-installed in a single kernel.

If you use the GPU version of the image, it comes with CUDA pre-installed as well.

As for adding a new kernel, you can add kernels from the command line, or even customize the dockerfile to add additional kernels (see the sample Dockerfile for the latest image [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-distribution/blob/main/build_artifacts/v1/v1.4/v1.4.3/Dockerfile) for reference).